# How to use onKeyUp within PHP echo?

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

Anyone know how to get the onKeyUp function to work within my PHP echo?  Trying to get the onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myTextCounter')" to work within my echoed input.  'myTextCounter' is giving me problems.

Thanks in Advance!

```
 echo '<input onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myTextCounter')"  type="text" name="description" id="description" value="'.$description.'" />'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the syntax highlighter show, you need to escape your single quotes:

```
echo '<input onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,\'myTextCounter\')"  type="text" name="description" id="description" value="'.$description.'" />'
```